# Create Exception for All AWS services behind firewall/Proxy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk

I am working behind the company firewall/Proxy which does not allow SSH to public network including AWS. I am trying to get the list of the entry which should be made exception in company network so all te services offered by AWS should be allowed in Private network and behind the proxy

Can you please share the same?

Comment: You should take a look at Direct connect: https://aws.amazon.com/directconnect/. The service allows you to create a dedicate network between AWS and your office. As well, most AWS services will be reachable via internet (S3, Dynamo, etc) using their FQDNs, so you mainly need to SSH to EC2 instances only.

Answer (score 2):

The AWS IP ranges are [public information](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-ip-ranges.html) but it seems likely that you are in for a bit of a surprise when you see the size of the list.

I have not counted recently, but there were multiple millions of IPv4 addresses in the list when I reviewed it, previously.  Allowing access to all of them is unlikely to be a viable strategy -- with that many destinations open, there's very little point in not just opening up access to the entire Internet.

Also, the list grows. You can subscribe to notifications, but you have to stay on top of it because it grows.  For example, from 2016-11-18 to 2016-12-01, my records show the IP ranges were updated 6 times (in two weeks).  This is a bit more often than normal, but it illustrates the drawback of whitelisting.  AWS does not pin its own services to specific addresses (e.g. "what is the IP address of s3-us-west-2?" is not a question with a single answer) for reasons of resiliency and scalability.

If you had only a small number of allowed hosts, such as EC2 instances with elastic IP addresses, these should allow you to tunnel out over SSH or TLS (openvpn) and that is probably a more viable solution, and a VPN connection might be more sensible, still... though a VPN connection by itself would only get you to *your* AWS resources, not AWS services like SNS, SQS, SES, DynamoDB, etc.